# g_object_new: assert from a call of g_application_send_notification()

Tags: c, gtk, mingw, assert, msys2

I use the newest GTK+ installed with MSYS2 and whenever I attempt to use
`g_application_send_notification()` it always results in the following
assert:

```
(Notification Project.exe:27780): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new:
assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

Why I think it is a bug - because I tried many code samples beside mines
(they are all quite like mines anyway), of people who got it working
(including notifaction by Lars Uebernickel) and it all makes the same
lament.
Assert, followed by crash. Now I really don't know what this means, as it
is probably within gtk internals, but I really hope some of you might have
a clue or experience with this.

- install (GNU coreutils) 8.25
- GIO version 2.52.3
- mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gtk-engine-unico 1.0.2-2 [installed]
- mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gtk3 3.22.16-1 [installed]
- mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gtkmm3 3.22.0-1 [installed]
- mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-spice-gtk 0.33-1 [installed]
- mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-webkitgtk3 2.4.11-4 [installed]
- mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk-engine-unico 1.0.2-2 [installed]
- mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3 3.22.16-1 [installed]
- mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3 3.22.0-1 [installed]
- mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-spice-gtk 0.33-1 [installed]
- mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-webkitgtk3 2.4.11-4 [installed]

---

An example of code that generates this assert:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define ICON_PATH "/path/trash_16x16.gif"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GApplication *app;

    app = g_application_new ("org.one", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    if(!app)
    {
        g_print ("Error app\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(g_application_register (app, NULL, NULL))
        {
            GNotification *notification;
            GFile *file;
            GIcon *icon;
            notification = g_notification_new ("one");
            g_notification_set_body (notification, "Hello world");
            file = g_file_new_for_path (ICON_PATH);
            icon = g_file_icon_new (file);
            g_notification_set_icon (notification, G_ICON (icon));
            g_application_send_notification (app, NULL, notification);
            g_object_unref (icon);
            g_object_unref (file);
            g_object_unref (notification);
            g_object_unref (app);
            g_print ("yes\n");
        }
        else
        {
            g_print ("no\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Is that anything I can do to bypass this problem, or perhaps even solve it?

Comment: First of all SO is not a GTK bug tracker, so why posting here? If you want us to reassure you, you should post an MCVE.

Comment: @EugeneSh Sorry if I misunderstand, but what is MCVE?
Also isn't it for programming-related problems. This is programming-related problem.

Comment: Your question would be better with your call to g_application_send_notification included in the question.  But I think it's probable it doesn't matter much, so :I am not downvoting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve And yes, it is for programming related questions. But I don't see a question here.

Comment: I think it could be useful to many users. I did a great research before posting and this question HAS BEEN asked before but never answered. If I see it get delete votes, I will delete it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Quite right. Seems I forgot to ask the question itself. Too much investigation I assume.

Comment: We still need to see a code which is generating the error.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Eugene, What would I do, without you

Comment: Are you sure it is from `g_application_send_notification` and not from `g_file_new_for_path` or `g_file_icon_new` which you are not checking for errors?

Comment: @EugeneSh. commenting-out the line always makes the program running without errors.

Comment: Also sometimes I test more pedantic program samples that try to do the same.. and everything is just the same. So it is not my fault. At least not in my codes.

Comment: I would say that probably D-Bus is absent from msys2 as all the gnome shell framework. I would dare to say that you are being very optimistic on trying to get a OS specific feature to work on a different OS.  I've tried your code on Fedora 26 and it runs without errors but the notification does not show up. Anyway, I think D-Bus can run on windows machines but that probably ain't enough. Services, like the notification object, must be running. Maybe some day...

Comment: @JoséFonte I am an optimistic person. `g_application_send_notification` was there since GTK 2.40, it is an ancient function and at least back then, writers wanted everything to work on windows as well. Now when more recent versions are being installed with msys2 only.. I don't know. Maybe I should try this with older version of GTK. If it works, I can try to recompile the older code into the newer

Comment: :) indeed and that it's a good characteristic :D. From what i just saw, there's a D-Bus package for msys2 but as said, that probably won't be enough. Good Luck @Malina

Comment: @JoséFonte Thank you :) If I find a solution. I will post it.

Comment: If you think it's a bug, check if it exists on http://bugs.gnome.org . If it doesn't, open a new bug and attach your code sample that repoduces it. Don't forget to fill the 'platform' field so people see the bug is reproduced under Windows. I have a MSYS2 install myself, I'll try to reproduce on my system.

Comment: @liberforce take a look: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788237

Answer (score 0):

There are no notification backends that work on W32, confirmed. Contributors do wanted, once, to create such, but the API (W32 toast notifications) that is needed is COM-only, and MinGW-w64 doesn't have the necessary headers for it, yet.
[image]

---

Looking at the glib [gio](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/tree/master/gio) source code and GNotificationBackend interface specifically, we can see that it is simple.

Now, you could just do it in GTK...OR we could do it the right way (TM) and implement a D-Bus server for it. The good thing about a notification server is that notifications can persist even after an application is terminated. Also, GTK already has backends for talking to a notification server, so you'd only need to enable these backends on W32 (at a glance, the code doesn't use anything that doesn't work on W32 already). Also, that way the server would transparently use `Shell_NotifyIcon` (on Windows 7 and earlier) or toast notifications (on Windows 8 and later; if you ever get an opportunity to implement these).

Another option if you want to maintain cross-platformability is to create `Shell_NotifyIcon` implementation in a DLL and if windows is detected use `Shell_NotifyIcon` if not, GNotification as you would.